# How to show that Archimedes' principle is equivalent to 'for any c>0, $\exists$ k $\in$ $\Bbb N$ such that k - 1 $\le$ c $\lt$ k'

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

Archimedes principle: For any two positive real numbers M, $\varepsilon$, there exist a k in $\Bbb N$ such that M < k * $\varepsilon$.

How can I show the above statement is equivalent to the below statement?

'for any c > 0, $\exists$ k $\in$ $\Bbb N$ such that k - 1 $\le$ c $\lt$ k'

Comment: That's not the principle I remember. In fact, as written, it is false. For example, $3.4$ and $3.5$.

Comment: Don Thousand, I'm not sure what you mean. If $M = 3.4$ and $\epsilon = 3.5$, then take $k = 1$. If $M = 3.5$ and $\epsilon = 3.4$, then take $k = 2$.

Comment: Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the statement is true. Let $M,\epsilon>0 0$ so $\frac{M}{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{R}$, by archimedean property, there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{M}{\epsilon}< k$ hence $M< k\epsilon$. Hope this will help you!